# Use mobile browser in selenium without emulating the device?

Tags: python, selenium, mobile, browser

I tried to write a script in python using selenium, that should automate uploading images to an image platform. However, the problem is, that the functionality for uploading pictures is only given, when you use a mobile browser (e.g. Safari on your iPhone). In a quick research, i found that selenium supports this, but as far as i understood it, this is only given if you emulate the device or connect a real device on your computer. Is there another way (maybe even another library?) for not having such an overhead (connecting or emulating the device), if you want to simulate an mobile browser using python?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Passing correct user agent should do the trick. Example with mobile Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: as of May 21 '19, chrome_options is now a deprecated argument, use options instead   https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver

Comment: I'm trying to do the same in JS, do you have ANY info that could help? I'm stuck since 2 days

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Specifying a Known Mobile Device**

To enable Mobile Emulation with a specific device name, the “mobileEmulation” dictionary must contain a “deviceName.” Use a valid device name from the DevTools Emulation panel as the value for “deviceName.”

```
from selenium import webdriver
mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "Nexus 5" }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities())
```

**Specifying Individual Device Attributes**

It is also possible to enable Mobile Emulation by specifying individual attributes. To enable Mobile Emulation this way, the “mobileEmulation” dictionary can contain a “deviceMetrics” dictionary and a “userAgent” string. The following device metrics must be specified in the “deviceMetrics” dictionary:

- “width” - the width in pixels of the device’s screen
- “height” - the height in pixels of the device’s screen
- “pixelRatio” - the device’s pixel ratio
- "touch" - whether to emulate touch events (defaults to true, usually
  does not need to be set)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19" }
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
```